# Network access in a windows phone 7 background agent

Tags: networking, background, wifi, agent

I have an app that uses a background agent to access the web and the local network via wi-fi - not cellular.  When the phone is locked, the wi-fi network is not available when the background agent runs - at least on the Samsung Focus Flash phone.  I also have an older LG Quantum phone which seems to work ok when the background agent runs - at least when it is plugged in.  I'm trying it now without being plugged in to see if that accounts for the difference in behaviour.

(UPDATE: IF the Samsung Flash Focus is plugged in (charging), it also provides wi-fi access when the background agent starts, so that explained the difference in behaviour between the Samsung and the LG Quantum.

So, now the ONLY question remaining is "How can you force the phone to turn on the wi-fi when the background agent starts AND it is NOT plugged in?" )

I use the method `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()` to test if the wi-fi network or any network is available when the background agent starts and also use

```
DeviceNetworkInformation.ResolveHostNameAsync(
                    new DnsEndPoint("microsoft.com", 80),
                    NameResolutionCallback,
                    null);
```

to determine which network is actually used.

Comment: is this related to android? in that case you can edit it to include the android tag. Besides it's not very clear what is being asked here I think...

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Phone 7, WiFi only stays if one of the following conditions is true:

- AC Power
- Back light on
- Data activity

Now, I believe some apps have a way to spoof data activity (something about background audio I think), but I am not sure how to.

See: http://lumiatips.com/keep-wifi-alive-for-windows-phone-homebrew.html

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to make background agent run every 30 minutes or so. If that is correct then I am afraid there is no way to do that. When the device is inactive windows phone does not schedule background agent to save battery. This is a good design.

However once you touch the power button and get the lock screen the background agent of your app should run in 2 - 3 seconds or so. That serves the purpose most of the time.

Generally background agent while making a network call, turns on the network be is Wifi or cellular.